# Removing spaces between letters and double spaces between words

Tags: java

I need to remove all the spaces between letters and make the double spaces into single spaces between the words.

So this (double spaces between words):

> h e l l o  m y  n a m e  i s  b o b

Will need to become this:

> hello my name is bob

I've tried
    `temp =  "h e l l o  m y  n a m e  i s  b o b"`
    `temp = temp.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");`
but it just removes all the spaces.

I managed to make it work by doing:
        `temp = temp.replace("  ", ".");`
        `temp = temp.replace(" ", "");`
        `temp = temp.replace(".", " ");`
But I would like a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the regex \s(?!\s). This basically says anything that is a space but doesn't have a space after it.

This would be used like this:

```
temp =  "h e l l o  m y  n a m e  i s  b o b";
temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s(?!\\s)", "");
System.out.println(temp);
```

**Outputs**: hello my name is bob

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worth noting that this works because it leaves the first space in a double space untouched, and kills the second one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
temp = temp.trim().replaceAll("(?<!\\s)\\s(?!\\s)", "");
temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler, more elegant way that does not include messing around with regex.

```
String yourString = "a s d  d g d d d  g g";
String finalstr = "";

for (String s: yourString.split(" ")) {
    if (s.equals(""))
        s = " ";
    finalstr += s;
}
System.out.println(finalstr);
```

**Output:** `asd dgddd gg`